# DnsQuery API returning 1460 immediately on multihomed PC

Tags: c++, windows, dns

When I run `nslookup -type=all _mysrv._tcp` on a multihomed PC, the command returns the correct SRV record information entered in DNS, showing an IP of the SRV record that points to a server in the 10.1.12.0 network.

However, when I call the API `DnsQuery_W` on this same multihomed PC, it returns immediately with error 1460 (`ERROR_TIMEOUT`).

When *would* `DnsQuery_W` return a value of 1460? In what scenario? Because if I put in a non-existent domain for the first parameter in `DnsQuery_W`, it just returns 9003, not 1460.

Any reason why? Is it the metric of the NICs causing the issue? Maybe it's **just** querying the Ethernet Adapter 2 first, so I'm not getting any records from the other NIC?

Here is the configuration of the two NICs:

`Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:`
`DHCP: No`
`IPv4: 192.168.1.100/24`
`Gw: [empty]`
`DNS: [empty]`

`Ethernet adapter Ethernet 1:`
`DHCP: Yes`
`IPv4: 10.1.12.100/24`
`Gw: 10.1.12.1`
`DNS: 10.1.12.100,10.1.12.101`

And here is fully working code that DnsQuery_W returns a status of 1460:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <windns.h>
#include <strsafe.h>


#pragma comment(lib, "dnsapi.lib")

void ResolveDNSSRVAddressEx(WCHAR *sServerFQDNOut, DWORD &dwErrorOut)
{
    PDNS_RECORDW pDnsRecord;
    WCHAR *sPrefixAndSuffix = new WCHAR[4096]();
    WCHAR* m_OutSRV = new WCHAR[4096]();


    StringCchCopyW(sPrefixAndSuffix, 4096, L"_mysrv._tcp.local.domain");
    
    dwErrorOut = 0;
    pDnsRecord = {0};

    DNS_STATUS status = DnsQuery_W(sPrefixAndSuffix, DNS_TYPE_SRV, DNS_QUERY_STANDARD, NULL, &pDnsRecord, NULL);
    if (status == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {       
        PDNS_RECORD cursor{};
            
        for (cursor = pDnsRecord; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor->pNext) 
            {
            if (cursor->Data.SRV.wPort == 0)
                break;

            StringCchPrintfW(m_OutSRV, 4096, L"%s|%s", m_OutSRV, cursor->Data.SRV.pNameTarget);
                    
            dwErrorOut = 0;
            }               
        }
    else
        {
        if (wcslen(m_OutSRV) == 0)
            dwErrorOut = status;
        }

    if (pDnsRecord)
        {       
        DNS_FREE_TYPE freetype = DnsFreeRecordListDeep;
        DnsRecordListFree(pDnsRecord, freetype);
        }

    if (wcslen(m_OutSRV))
        StringCchCopyW(sServerFQDNOut, 4096, m_OutSRV);

}


int main()
{
    WCHAR* sServerFQDNOut = new WCHAR[4096]();
    DWORD dwErr{};

    ResolveDNSSRVAddressEx(sServerFQDNOut, dwErr);
}
```